# don't understand how qml svg path works

Tags: qt, svg, path, qml

In the official QML documentation, all they put for SvgPaths is:

```
Path {
    startX: 50; startY: 50
    PathSvg { path: "L 150 50 L 100 150 z" }
}
```

which normally makes a triangle, but it doesn't work :(

Does it need a PathView ?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't draw shapes with the `Path` API. You'd need to use e.g. `Canvas` or `QQuickPaintedItem` for that. The image in the documentation for `SvgPath` is meant to illustrate the path that would be created by the accompanying snippet.

It is mentioned in the [documentation for Path](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-path.html) that it:

> Defines a path for use by PathView

It also says:

> A Path is composed of one or more path segments - PathLine, PathQuad, PathCubic, PathArc, PathCurve, PathSvg.

If you follow the links to [PathView's documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html#details), you can see how they're all used together:

```
PathView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: ContactModel {}
    delegate: delegate
    path: Path {
        startX: 120; startY: 100
        PathQuad { x: 120; y: 25; controlX: 260; controlY: 75 }
        PathQuad { x: 120; y: 100; controlX: -20; controlY: 75 }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. PathView, as it says in the documentation, "lays out model-provided items on a path", so it requires a model and a delegate. The question asks how to draw the SVG path as a triangle, as shown in the documentation.

Comment: Well, it does. The image in the documentation illustrates a path that would be created by the accompanying code, for use with `PathView` (notice all of the related links point to `PathView`). At no point did the question ask about "drawing a triangle", but thanks for downvoting me based on the assumption that your understanding of the question is the only possible correct one. Anyhow, I've updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Fair point, Mitch. Thanks for updating the answer too. Downvote replaced with upvote.